# remove Repeat values from a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to accomplish a few tasks in Haskell:

1. Find the maximum of a list, along with the number of times it occurs:

   ```
   maxCount [2,4,7,2,3] --> [7,1]
   ```
2. Remove repeated values from a list

   ```
   delRep [1,3,2,1,4] --> [3,2,4]
   ```
3. Delete all instances of an element from a list:

   ```
   delete [1,3,4,1] 1 --> [3,4]
   ```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly don't you understand? We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: @John L I'd say: Is this homework? If so, then try first, else I refuse to answer unless you pay me. A lot.

Comment: @Ziyao Wei: I'm in a good mood, so I tried to be helpful.  I considered writing an obfuscated response, but I didn't want to work that hard.

Comment: @John L you could at least use `pointfree` to obfuscate a bit!

Comment: I edited the question so it looks presentable (and I added the homework tag), but I still dislike the manner in which it was asked. You may be interested in using [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle)

Answer (score 2):

Question 1.

```
maxAndReps l = let m = maximum l
                   reps = length $ filter (== m) l
               in [m,reps]
```

This solution has very bad asymptotic performance because the list is traversed twice.  Ideally, a solution would find the maximum and count the repetitions in one pass.  If you write `maximum`, `filter`, and `length` in terms of a fold, you should see how to combine them into a single pass.

Also, it would be more natural to return a tuple instead of a list.

Question 2.  Look at using `Data.Set.Set`.  Also, does the output list need to be in the same order?  If not, there's a particularly easy solution.

Question 3.  My above answer for question 1 covers this.  That function removes all non-maximum values from the list, which is exactly this problem.  Just figure out how that one works, and you'll have this solved as well.

Comment: Are you sure this is *O(n^2)*? I.e. shouldn't `maximum` an `filter` be both just *O(n)*?

Comment: This is surely O(n), not O(n^2) let alone O(kn^2). The only asymptotic performance concern I see is the linear usage of memory because the list is traversed more than once.

Comment: @hvr and @Rotsor, you're both right.  Teach me to go on SO after my bedtime.  I've fixed it up a bit.

Comment: +1 Good guidance without solving his problems for him.

Answer (score -2):

With no builtin functions.. looks really ugly :D

Changed the first a little bit, didn't like that it only works on integers.

```
-- 1.
maxic :: Ord a => [a] -> (a, Integer)
maxic xs = (x,c)
  where x = maxi xs
         where maxi :: Ord a => [a] -> a
               maxi [] = error "empty list"
               maxi (x:xs) = iter xs x
                 where iter [] m = m
                       iter (x:xs) m | x > m = iter xs x
                       iter (_:xs) m = iter xs m
        c = cnt xs x
          where cnt :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Integer
                cnt (x:xs) e | x==e = 1 + (cnt xs e)
                cnt (_:xs) e = cnt xs e
                cnt _ _ = 0

-- 2.
remrep :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
remrep xs = reverse (iter xs [])
  where iter (x:xs) res | elem x res = iter xs (filter (/= x) res)
        iter (x:xs) res = iter xs (x:res)
        iter [] res = res

-- 3.
remo :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
remo [] e = []
remo (x:xs) e | x==e = remo xs e
remo (x:xs) e = (x : remo xs e)
```

Ok, I cheated, I used, filter but you can use `remo` for that, and `elem` should be trivial to write.

Comment: -1 for doing his homework for him in full, especially with no guidance or explanation.

Comment: What guidance could you give for excersie 3? Seriously, if he is too lazy, no guidance on earth will help... I did this just for fun, learned the basics a couple of days ago.

Comment: maybe just point your finger toward the `filter` function, and make him figure out how to use it.

Comment: he is probably at basic level (learning pattern matching, handling list, all that stuff, you know...) and supposed to solve this without any "fancy" builtins. that's not what I would call guiding.

Comment: then don't say anything about #3?  Get him started on the others.  I understand that you were just having fun implementing this, but that doesn't mean you need to give him extra opportunities to be lazy.  Anyway, I'm just voting in accordance with my values.

Comment: got it ! =D thanks for the help  .                                     and;Do not hard. I'm just the first step